# Allow all users full read/write access to CIFS share with automount/autofs

Tags: linux, permissions, cifs, automounting, autofs

How can I configure autofs/automount so that every single user has full access to an auto-mounted CIFS share?

---

### More information

This is what I currently have configured:

**/etc/auto.master**

```
/mnt    /etc/auto.htpc  --ghost
```

**/etc/auto.htpc**

```
htpc -fstype=cifs,username=content,password=content ://192.168.0.2/Content
```

It works perfectly fine, provided the user is root.

I've tried adding `uid=fred,guid=fred` but that just ends up allowing the "fred" user read/write access, all other users get "Permission denied".

I've also tried adding `umask=000` but then only root has access.

Answer (score 0):

Change your /etc/auto.htpc to:

```
htpc -fstype=cifs,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=content,password=content ://192.168.0.2/Content
```

That will allow any user to write and read from the mountpoint